# Surjectivity of natural morphism between multiplicative modulo groups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer and $d$ be a divisor of $n$. Then there is a natural group homomorphism:
\begin{align}\varphi:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} &\to (\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\\ [x] &\mapsto [x] \end{align}
I want to know whether $\varphi$ is surjective. This may be a silly question, but I don't know where to look for the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041690/242) and its links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varphi$ is surjective. By the Chinese remainder theorem it suffices to show this when $n$ and $d$ are powers of the same prime, say $p^a$ and $p^b$ where $b \le a$. In this case it's clear because every lift of a unit $\bmod p^b$ is a unit $\bmod p^a$ (since it's not divisible by $p$).

Comment: In general we need to be careful because it's not true that if $\phi : R \to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism then the induced map $R^{\times} \to S^{\times}$ is surjective. However, it is true if $R$ is a local ring and $S$ is the quotient of $R$ by a power of its maximal ideal, which suffices for this case.

Comment: I recall that there general case was discussed [on MO in 2010](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31495), and also somewhere here iirc.

Answer (score 0):

By [$\,\rm\color{#c00}{co}$prime Dirichlet:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) $\,(a,d,n)\overset{d\,\mid\, n}=(a,d)=1\,\Rightarrow\, \exists\, x\in\Bbb Z\!:\ (a+d\:\!x,\,n)=1.\ \ \rm\small QED$

**Remark** $ $ This theorem on $\rm\color{#c00}{co}$primes in arithmetic progressions has a very short high-school level [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) using a simple variation (by Stieltjes) on Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.